# List exposed OSGi services in JBoss AS 7.2 Management Console

Tags: osgi, jboss7.x

I'm running [JBoss AS 7.2](http://www.jboss.org/jbossas) (in standalone mode) and I've imported a couple of bundles. When I look in the management console on `http://localhost:9990`, and go to *Runtime Operations -> OSGi*, the bundles are all listed as Active, and the output in the terminal where I'm running JBoss shows some status messages that they all started OK.

However, I'm having some trouble accessing services that should be exposed by these bundles. In order to find out if it the configuration of the bundles themselves that is the problem, or the client code, I'd like JBoss to list all services exposed/provided by a given bundle, so I can match that against my expectations.

Is this possbile? Where, and how?

Comment: And if not, is there an API I can use to roll my own?

Answer (score 0):

Not specific to JBoss, but why don't you try out [Xray](http://softwaresimplexity.blogspot.se/2012/05/x-rays-for-osgi.html), by Peter Kriens. Excellent! Requires [Aache Felix Web Console](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-web-console.html). The web console might be enough, but the visualization provided by Xray is hard to beat.